# Adding fields to apostrophe-richt-text

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like make `apostrophe-rich-text-widgets` configurable, allowing to set the number of text columns. (This number will then translate to a CSS class, that's the trivial part.)

How do I `addFields` to the rich text widget correctly? The following will show the *Edit Rich Text* button, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

```
// my-app/lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
    beforeConstruct: function(self,options) {

        //options.contextualOnly = !_.isUndefined(options.contextualOnly) ? options.contextualOnly : false;
        options.contextualOnly = false;

        options.addFields = [
            {
                name: 'nr_columns',
                type: 'integer',
                min: 1,
                max: 3,
                label: 'Number of Columns'
            }
        ].concat(options.addFields || []);
    }
};
```

**Update**

So I have implemented a wrapper widget, which lets me configure the number of columns as an integer, and adds an `apostrophe-rich-text` widget as a singleton.

```
// lib/modules/my-wrapper/index.js
module.exports = {                                                
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',                                 
    label: 'Multi-column Text',                                   
    skipInitialModal: true,                                     
    addFields: [                                                  
        {                                                         
            name: 'nr_columns',                                   
            label: 'Nr. of Columns',                              
            type: 'integer',                                      
            required: true,                                       
            min: 1,                                               
            max: 3                                                
        },                                                        
        {                                                         
            name: 'text',                                         
            label: 'Text',                                        
            type: 'singleton',                                    
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-rich-text',                   
            contextual: true                                      
        }                                                         
    ]                                                             
};
```

When I add the wrapper widget to a page, no rich-text editor can be seen. What's required in `views/widget.html` to make this work?

**Update 2**

Here's my `views/widget.html`, but I'm not at all sure what should be in there. (*Edit: replaced `widget.content` below with `data.widget.content` - still same problem.*)

```
{% set n = data.widget.nr_columns %}

<div data-rich-text class="apos-rich-text text-row {% if n == 2 %}two-column{% endif %}">
    {{ data.widget.content }}
</div>
```

**Update 3**

My `views/widget.html`:

```
<div class="text-row {% if n == 2 %}two-column{% elif n == 3%}three-column{% endif %}">
    {{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'text', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {toolbar:['Bold','Italic'],contextualOnly:true}) }}
</div>
```

My `index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Multi-column Text',
    //skipInitialModal: true,
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'nr_columns',
            label: 'Nr. of Columns',
            type: 'integer',
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'text',
            contextualOnly: true,
            type: 'singleton',
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-rich-text'
        }
    ]
};
```

What I see after adding the widget to a page:

[image: After adding the widget]

Comment: The rich text widget operates outside the normal boundaries of widget extensions, much harder to override.
I would instead make a wrapper widget with a rich text singleton and column count integer as its schema. You can make the widget `skipInitialModal:true` and the RT singleton `contextual:true` if you want it behave like a normal rich text widget upon placement. Then implement columns as you would. Not sure that is a satisfying answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: Please post your wrapper widget's `views/widget.html`

Comment: Done @StuartRomanek

Comment: It appears that, when adding the singleton, the `apostrophe-rich-text` widget gets not actually added; instead, a button to add a rich text area appears. This may be the reason for why it is empty. How can I tell apostrophe to add a `apostrophe-rich-text` widget, instead of the button to add one?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the same effect as Apostrophe's normal `apostrophe-rich-text` widget, you need actually add that singleton to your widget's template like

```
<div class="some-wrapper">
   {{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'RICH_TEXT_WIDGET_SCHEMA_NAME', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {...RICHTEXT_OPTIONS_HERE}) }}
</div>
```

Comment: So I removed the `singleton` from `index.js`, my `views/widget.html` contains `{{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'multi-column-text', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {toolbar:['Bold','Italic'],contextual:true}) }}`

I can see multiple columns now, but there's still a button saying _Add Rich Text_ instead of the actual widget. What am I missing?

Comment: not totally sure what you mean. Add Rich Text is empty state for a rich text widget. You need to keep the singleton field in your widget's `index.js` because Apostrophe will need it for various sanitization operations. `contextual: true` in the widget's options is not going to be recognized, this is a flag for the modal editor only. Is your content now saving?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the original question again with `views/widget.html`, `index.js` and a screenshot.

Comment: This looks correct. Still confused about what you expect to be happening.

Comment: I expect the "add rich text" button to disappear and an input/text field to show up instead, as seen in the apostrophe-rich-text widget. I would like to enter text without having to click the button first.

Comment: Ah, you want to automatically initialize the rich text editor like a stand-alone rich text widget would do when you put it on the page. I think the short answer is there is no out-of-the-box way to do that, but I could imagine it being a small PR to apostrophe core and the rich-text widget's options.